# How to create npm package for react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-publish

I've created this great string parser which parse the string and display only 5 lines or approx 1000(1000+ it'll adjust according to word length) characters(whichever is less) on screen.
I've published my package on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-read-more) but on installing it I get this error:

```
Module parse failed: C:\xampp\htdocs\gitlab\communityFrontend\node_modules\react-simple-read-more\src\string-parser.js Unexpected token (77:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (77:12)
```

here is [package.json](https://github.com/oztek22/react-simple-read-more/blob/master/package.json) of that same package
Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: That might be an error caused by settings of your webpack. Could you paste it if you have it?

Comment: I have not created any webpack config file, I use their default config only maybe I've done silly mistake in pckage.json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you experience is due to the fact that your [string--parser](https://github.com/oztek22/react-simple-read-more/blob/master/src/string-parser.js)
is not a pure javascript file. But instead it uses JSX syntax. And that is the reason why it complains about unexpected token such as `<` in the following line:

```
<div style={{width:'100%',wordWrap: 'break-word'}}>
```

You must transpile your JSX sources to pure javascript before publishing to NPM - so anyone can consume them. And surely do not name JSX files with JS extension to avoid such confusions in the future.